# Rust Notify (Filewatcher) is not debouncing events

Tags: rust, notify, tauri

I am trying to create a filewatcher in rust using the notify-crate. Since I don't want it to spam all events but rather just tell once if a change occured I tried using a debounced filewatcher:

```
pub fn create_watcher(path: &str) -> Result<(ReadDirectoryChangesWatcher, Receiver<DebouncedEvent>), notify::Error> {
    let (sender, receiver) = channel();
    // should debounce for 10s
    let mut watcher = watcher(sender, Duration::from_secs(10))?;
    watcher.watch(path, RecursiveMode::Recursive)?;
    Ok((watcher, receiver))
}
```

Yet it still creates an event for every operation it notices. The usage of the function can be seen below:

```
#[tauri::command]
fn listen_installed(window: Window) {
    thread::spawn(move || {
        let username = env::var("USERNAME").unwrap();
        let channel = create_watcher(&format!("C:\\Users\\{}\\scoop\\apps", username)).unwrap();
    
        loop {
            match channel.1.recv() {
                Ok(ok) => {
                    window.emit("installed-packages-changed", None::<&str>);
                },
                Err(e) => println!("{:?}", &e.to_string()),
            };
        }
    });
}
```

Haven't I used the file-watcher properly or did I missunderstand what a "Debounced-Watcher" is?